# How do I use 'OR' operator to return all rows if string is empty in linq to sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-5

I've a linq query :

```
var Employees = db.EmployeeMasterAs
.Where(x => x.SystemCode == SysCode && x.EmployeeCode == EmpCode)
.ToList();
```

the above query works fine if all values in the where clause are provided. If `EmpCode` is supplied a value, it returns the corresponding data, which works fine. However, I've no idea about how to return all rows if `EmpCode` is not supplied.

If I were to use SQL, I would have done it this way :

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeMasterAs 
WHERE SystemCode == @SysCode AND (EmployeeCode == @EmpCode or '')
```

I've no idea how to translate the above query into linq syntax. Any Help will be deeply appreciated, Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can even write something like this
`...&& (EmpCode == null || x.EmployeeCode ==  EmpCode) )`

which i find simplier than @Dr Ivol

Comment: It is indeed a better solution than mine

Comment: Perfect answer!